# WFFM and MVC validation

Tags: wffm, mvc

When using WFFM with MVC are the validation items under

```
/sitecore/system/Modules/Web Forms for Marketers/Settings/Validation
```

actually used, or are those items WebForms-specific? Does all MVC client validation take place within jQuery / unobtrusive validation?

Comment: Not all validation is done client side (some fields do/did not have JQuery validators set) but *all fields douse client side validation* since this ia best practice - Javascript can be disabled for example.